# How do i post a JSON object that includes an image to a server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Below is the code I use to post information to the server in JSON format.

```
    NSData *jsonData = [dict dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *jsonLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[jsonData length]];
    //Initiating the request
    urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [urlRequest setURL:url];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setValue:jsonLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    //[urlRequest setValue:@"applcation/x-www-form-urlencoded;" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"applcation/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:jsonData];
```

Below is the data post part.

```
    NSString *urlStg = nil;
    NSString *dict = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"keyword\":\"%@\",\"email\":\"%@\",\"password\":\"%@\"}",@"login",@"xx@aaa.com",@"2221"];

    //Parsing JSON data

    _LZjsonfetcher = [[JSONFetcher alloc] init];

    [_LZjsonfetcher setDelegate:self];

    [_LZjsonfetcher postDataParsed:dict url:urlStg delegate:nil key:nil];
```

I've had success connecting to the server and getting the JSON to return.
But, the problem is that I don't have any idea on how to submit an image to the server with JSON. I've tried to find a sample with no success. Does JSON not support image upload? Do I need to find another way to upload an image to the server? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Look into NSURLSessionUploadTask. Here is a link https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/urlloadingsystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW15

Comment: u can't directly stored the image into the server, u need to follow the 3 steps, 1. convert UIImage to NSData 2. Convert NSData to NSString 3. finally u store the string Value to the server,

Comment: the retrieve is also the reverse process ,k

Comment: so means i still can use json, i just need do extra works for process the IMAGE?

Comment: your reverse part means i need do in my php that side? thanks

Comment: If you want to embed the image into the json message then you need to convert its bytes to String. Try encoding its bytes to base64 code and then upload it. In the server side you need to decode the message and construct the image.

Comment: Converting image to string via NSData may not be enough. Also try considering base64 encoding and the other server should also be aware of this conversion.

Comment: i had try to encode to base64, but after convert and post the server. the json sent is keep fail, means if i remove the image data to post, it will return for success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you could do it using the suggestions here, I think it is worth looking at the `AFNetworking` framework which makes the entire networking process easier in my opinion.
Using this framework, here's how you could send a JSON with an image:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager * manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] init];
NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 1.0);
NSDictionary * jsonParameters = @{@"key":@"value"};

[manager POST:@"http://myURL.com" parameters:jsonParameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"attachment" fileName:@"myImage.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
  } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success!");
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure!");
    }];
```

The framework is very flexible and there's so much more you can do with it - I highly recommend it.

Comment: hello, thanks you for your sugget. I have stranger json but how can I use your method with this? here is my json ( include base64 with key inside ):
https://pastebin.com/NSRViJ59

Comment: @kemdo as long as you have a valid JSON object which is represented as an `NSDictionary` the same method should work. Please note however that this answer was written a long time ago and that the AFNetworking framework has changed since then (if you're writing in Swift you should look at Alamofire instead). Also, Apple has greatly improved their own networking libraries so you might just prefer to use them directly.

Answer (score 1):

Use base64 encoding, which will convert data to a string that will be compatible with json.

```
UIImage* image = nil;
NSData* dataImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSString* base64Image = [dataImage base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

[dictionary setObject:base64Image forKey:@"image"];
```

Now on the server side you will need to decode the base64 string and save it out as an image file, php:

```
$dictionary = NULL;
$base64_image = $dictionary->image;
$image = base64_decode($base64_image);
file_put_contents('/image.png', $image);
```

Comment: i had try to encode to base64, but after convert and post the server. the json sent is keep fail, means if i remove the image data to post, it will return for success.

Comment: @Lazarus how large is the http request with the image? Perhaps it is exceeding your server's upload size limit.